# Why would this a pair of E5-2670 cpus be faster than 4 E5-2640 cpus for large matrix diagonalisation problems?

Tags: parallel-computing, fortran, mpi, lapack

Not really much more to say;

Of several computers available for use, these are two of the larger ones; one has 2x [E5-2670](http://ark.intel.com/products/64595/), and the other has 4x [E5-4640](http://ark.intel.com/products/64603/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-4640-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI). The problems we're looking at essentially boil down to large matrix diagonalisation problems (i.e. i have been dealing with 125K rank matrices, and in the past have looked at larger ones. Both sparse and non sparse, using [PARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~kristyn/parpack_home.html)).

All intuition would tell me that the Quad CPU 4640 should be much faster, but it's not, and I can't work out why at all. Both have hyperthreading enabled, both have 250GB ram.

Could it be that the gains from the parallelisation of PARPACK beyond 16 cores just start to diminish, and are not worth adding the additional processors due to the increase in inter cpu communcation required?

The codes are written in fortran if that makes much difference.

Comment: Hyperthreading usually kills performance for HPC apps, so it's entirely possible that the performance difference between two separate nodes and one shared-memory node is entirely masked by the drop in performance due to the use of hyperthreads. Also, it might matter how you are doing your parallelism. Is it entirely using MPI, or are you doing MPI+OpenMP?

Comment: It's likely that this computation is limited by memory bandwidth effects.  What are the memory configurations on the two systems?

Comment: According to the first reference I checked, the E5-4640 is clocked at 2.4 GHz, vs. 2.6 GHz for the E5-2670.  Both have 4 DDR3 memory channels.  I'm not too surprised that the extra cores with no extra memory bandwidth don't help with something like this.

Comment: The E5-2670 is actually faster than the E5-4640 from what I can see. So a silly question is, have you made sure that you're actually running on all cores? Assuming the answer is yes, my guess (like Brians) would be that you're limited by memory bandwith.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, there should be additional memory bandwidth added with every socket added since the memory controllers are integrated with the chips.

Comment: @BillBarth right.  I was thinking that these were both 2 chip systems (which would have the same bandwidth however many processor cores per socket.)  With 4 sockets vs. 2 sockets, you should get twice the bandwidth.  So, perhaps the problem is that the code just doesn't parallelize effectivey.  I wonder what the utilization of the cores is?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has asked for any quantitative performance numbers. How big is the difference?

Comment: To address a load of these comments, much of the parallelisation is just from parallel libraries (like parpack), but the benchmarks i found don't go up to the sizes of matrices we've been looking at (largest i went to was ~450K rank, but was quite sparse. then others were around 100K rank, but ~10-15% non zero) as for how many cores they were using, in both cases it was as many as possible, and hyperthreading was on on both computers.

Comment: @BillBarth The reason the hyperthreading is on on these machines is that there's no queuing system on them, as it has not worked in the past in the department. hyperthreading apparently helps when people ignore that a machine is already fully loaded and just start running stuff on it.

Comment: @will, there's almost no point in putting a queue on one node. You should look around to see if you can get access to local, state, or national cluster resources.

Comment: I have an account on HECToR, but i only use that for the *really* large jobs. There are about 10 nodes of reasonable size, and then about 50 more smaller (i.e. desktop i7s) for about 10 active users at anyone time. The problem is solely that people work in bursts, and will submit jobs to everything. And when that happens with more than one person at a time, there's a fair bit of complaining. There's money budgeted to get more large computers, but obviously we want to get ones which will work for us best - and simple intuition has not succeeded with these two large ones!